# Task: "Assigned to" must be prefilled with specific User or Group

Tags: tasks, online

In Tasks I have a ContentType called Admittance, which basically tells Facillity Services to hand-over a set of keys to an associate.
So when a task of this type is being created, Facillity Services (as a group is Sharepoint) should automatically assigned to the task.
The creator of the task should not have to make any considerations about whom to assign the task to.

A workflow is not possible due to the architecture of the solution.

Thanks in advance for any input

/jacob

Answer (score 0):

Use a calculated column - the formula would be something like this:

=IF ([Column1]=YourValue, "OK", "Not OK")

You might want to modify the formula to something like:

=IF ([ContentType]=Admittance, "Facility Services", "Another User Name")

**NOTES**

The logic is if the ContentType field has the value 'Admittance', your calculated column will return the value 'Admittance'.  Otherwise if the ContentType field does not have the value 'Admittance', it will return "Another User Name" (or whatever text you define).

*HOW TO MAKE A CALCULATED COLUMN*

Go in List Settings>Create Column>Calculated Column.

Comment: Hi Tally,
actually a rather good idea, but unfortunately it is not going to fullfill my requirements.
It is imperative, that it is the 'Assigned to' field that is being prefilled.